# MySQL Time Diffs Before Concat (Same Row)

Tags: mysql

I have query below:

```
SELECT year(time_of_creation), month(time_of_creation), group_concat(time_to_sec(last_updated) - time_to_sec(time_of_creation)) from my_table where status='s' group by year(time_of_creation), month(time_of_creation);
```

What I expect this to do is if there is a table with the following columns:

```
status
time_of_creation
last updated
```

I want each entry to be bucketed by `(year, month)` and I want a comma separated list of the time difference in seconds for each row between the two fields (`last_updated`, `time_of_creation`).

However, my query above seems to be returning numbers that don't match what I visually inspect through the table.

Am I writing my query incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This.

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT_WS(" , ", year(time_of_creation),month(time_of_creation)) 
  , 
  group_concat(TIME(time_to_sec(last_updated) - time_to_sec(time_of_creation))) 
  FROM my_table 
  where status='s'
    and IFNULL(last_updated,0) > 0
  group by year(time_of_creation), month(time_of_creation);
```

Comment: Actually, I'm looking at the docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat, Is `group_concat(TIME(time_to_sec(last_updated) - time_to_sec(time_of_creation)))` considered a valid expression?

Comment: yes, here we returned seconds difference in time format